# FPS Android game that moves the gun as user swipes the screen

Tags: animation, unityscript

I am Making a First Person shooter game for android. Gun moves in all directions I swipe left right up or down. But the speed is so slow. How can i increase it's Speed.Here is my code.

```
void FixedUpdate ()
{
    foreach (Touch t in Input.touches)
        if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            initialTouch = t;
        } 
        else if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Moved && !hasSwiped)
        {
            float deltaX = initialTouch.position.x - t.position.x;
            float deltaY = initialTouch.position.y - t.position.y;
                //distance formula
            distance = Mathf.Sqrt((deltaX * deltaX) +(deltaY * deltaY));
            bool swipeSideways = Mathf.Abs (deltaX) > Mathf.Abs (deltaY);
            if (distance > 100f)
            {
                if (swipeSideways && deltaX > 0) {
                    this.transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (0, 30f, 0), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                }

                else if (swipeSideways && deltaX <=0)// swipe right
                {
                    this.transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (0, 30f, 0), -rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                }


                hasSwiped = true;
            }


        } 

        else if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        { 
            initialTouch = new Touch ();
            hasSwiped = false;
        }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a global float called `speed` at set it to some number, and let's set it to 10 for starters(the higher the number, the higher the speed that the gun moves). And then replace this:

```
rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime
```

with this:

```
rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime * speed
```

and this:

```
-rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime
```

with this:

```
-rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime * speed
```

Comment: Or, you know, simply increase rotationSpeed...